# Error C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::ofstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, mfc, file-handling

I am working on an `MFC Application` and have declared an `ofstream` object in a class header, the object is then initialized in the constructor and used in the other methods of the same class. I got the following error:

> Error C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::ofstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

*I have searched about this issue and found many solutions i.e. there are some suggestions to:*

- Use *`#include <string>`*
- Use *`#include <iostream>`*
- Use *`#include <istream>`*

And some other information that I got is about when does this error occur. But all that I got doesn't fix my issue. Kindly have a look at my code:

**CGroupComboBox.h :**

```
private:
    std::ofstream fptr;
```

**CGroupComboBox.cpp :**

```
//Constructor
CGroupComboBox::CGroupComboBox()
    : m_dropdownListAutoWidth(true)
    , m_autocomplete(true)
    , m_selectionUndoByEscKey(true)
{
    fptr.open("test.txt",std::ios::out); //Initialization of fptr
}

//Member Function
int CGroupComboBox::FindString(int nStartAfter, LPCTSTR lpszString) const
{
    fptr<<"I am FindString.\n"; //Trying to write something

    //Other Code
}

//Destructor
CGroupComboBox::~CGroupComboBox()
{
    //Other Code

    fptr.close();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared this member function with qualifier const

```
int CGroupComboBox::FindString(int nStartAfter, LPCTSTR lpszString) const
                                                                    ^^^^^
```

Thus `this` in this case has type `const CGroupComboBox *` and you may not change data member of the object pointed to by `this`.

However this statements

```
fptr<<"I am FindString.\n"; //Trying to write something
```

requires non-const data member `fptr`.

So the compiler issues an error.

One of solutions is to use specifier `mutable` for data member `fptr`

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can see my mistake :)

Answer (score 4):

Since `fptr` can be modified from `const`-qualified functions, it should be marked `mutable`. Alternatively, you can use a `const_cast` in `FindString`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can see my mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

> Error C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::ofstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

That is the answer. `<<` tries to manipulate the object and your object is const.

To solve the problem, remove const from you FindString method

Comment: ...although a method called `FindXXX` should arguably always be written in terms of being `const`, no?

Comment: Hmmm. It should ;) then go for Davids solution.